# Typewriter effect text glitch in react

Tags: reactjs

I imported react-simple-typewriter in my project and the words in my Typewriter array glitches and the first letter of each word appears next to my first sentence. I want my first line of text to be still and not move and when the array of words={["MUSIC", "ART", "TALENT", "PUBLISHING"]} disappears.

Landing.js

```
import Typewriter from "react-simple-typewriter";

<h2 id="text">
              THE FUTURE OF{" "}
              <span>
                {/* Style will be inherited from the parent element */}
                <Typewriter
                  loop
                  cursor
                  cursorStyle="_"
                  typeSpeed={60}
                  deleteSpeed={40}
                  delaySpeed={1000}
                  words={["MUSIC", "ART", "TALENT", "PUBLISHING"]}
                />
                {/* <Typist sentences={["MUSIC", "ART", "TALENT", "PUBLISHING"]} /> */}
              </span>
            </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added inline-block to allow me to position the text element keeping the text width & height properties can be set, or we can think of a block-level element, that doesn’t have to start with a new line. Inline-block remains inline with all text around the element and appears the same as an inline.

```
<h2 id="text">THE FUTURE OF </h2>
            <h2 id="text">
              <span
                style={{
                  display: "inline-block",
                }}
              >
                
                <Typewriter
                  loop
                  cursor
                  cursorStyle="_"
                  typeSpeed={60}
                  deleteSpeed={200}
                  delaySpeed={1000}
                  words={["MUSIC", "ART", "TALENT", "PUBLISHING"]}
                />
               
              </span>
            </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

After having a lot of problems myself too I had to write my own Typewriter component fully compatible with Typescript and the newest react version. Simply install it with `npm i react-ts-typewriter`, import using `import Typewriter from 'react-ts-typewriter'` and call it using `<Typewriter text="Example text" />`or `<Typewriter text={["arrays", "also", "work"]} />`.